# First positive root using the fixed point iterative method

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find why when using fixed point method to find the first positive root, the method always converge to the highest negative root (closest to zero).

I have the function: $f(x)=cos(\frac{x.\pi}{9})+8.sin(x\pi)$

now $f(x)=cos(\frac{x.\pi}{9})+8.sin(x\pi)=0$

The interval that I chose was [1, 1.5] since f(1)= +ve and f(1.5) = -ve

I solved for x and I know that the way to solve for x is :$ x=\frac{\sin^{-1}(-\frac{1}{8} (\cos\frac{(x\pi)}{9}))}{\pi} = g(x)$, since the derivative of |g'(x)| < 1 where x = 1 since f(1) = 0.94 is closer to 0 than f(1.5) = -7.13

If I try to find the value where it converges, I get x=-0.039. Even if I choose [1.5 ,2], which is the next time the signal changes, it also converges to x=-0.039.

I need the first positive root so how can I calculate it using the fixed method point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your $\sin^{-1}$ is implemented as $\arcsin$, your iteration has no hope of converging to a root larger than $1$, because $\arcsin$ of something is between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, so that divided by $\pi$ is between $-1/2$ and $1/2$. However, $\pi-\arcsin(x)$ is another value of $\sin^{-1}(x)$, which is then between $\pi/2$ and $3 \pi/2$. After division by $\pi$ you get a range of $1/2$ to $3/2$ which is where your desired root is. So your iteration might converge with that modification. (Though I do not really understand where the $8$ in your formula came from; I get good results when I remove it.)

You can also try Newton iteration, which worked for me with $x_0=1$.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake, I edited my question.The function is $ cos (\frac{x.\pi}{9})+ 8.sin(x.\pi) $ I also tried other methods such as Newton Raphson and I got the first positive root. I cannot understand why using the Fixed method point I do not have the same positive root my result will always converges for the largest negative root.

Comment: @user290335 With the $\pi-\arcsin$ variant and the $8$ present, I get convergence with your iteration and $x_0=1$.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what is the $\pi - arcsin $ can you explain it better? Thanks

Comment: @user290335 $\sin^{-1}$ is multivalued. The standard branch of it is called $\arcsin$ and returns values between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. So if you implement your iteration in a standard language (C, Python, Matlab, ...) with $\sin^{-1}$ written as "asin", you will never see a root larger than $1/2$. However, $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin(y)$, so $\pi-\arcsin(x)$ is another value of $\sin^{-1}(x)$, and is between $\pi/2$ and $3 \pi/2$. This gives the range where your root is.

Comment: I tried what you said, but I got a value that is close to the second positive root and not the first positive root. Do you know why? I did: $\pi-(arsin((-1/8)*cos((pi*x)/9))))$ at $x=\frac{3.\pi}{2}$

Comment: @user290335 I'm not sure I understand. The first positive root is just slightly larger than $1$, and this is the result that I get. (In the formula you just wrote you did not divide by $\pi$, but it is otherwise the same as what I did.)

Comment: I know that the first positive root is 1.03729 but using what you said I got x=3.13. Probably I am doing the calculations wrong.

Comment: @user290335 In Matlab syntax you should have (pi-asin((-1/8)*cos((pi/9)*x)))/pi

Comment: I forgot to divide by pi. When I divide it by pi and if x0=(3pi)/2 I will obtain x=0.997053, after that if x=0.997053 I will obtain that x=1.375 finally if x=1.375 , I will obtain x=1.03729 and I found the first positive root. Thank you very much for your help.